# How to show only one row than multiple duplicates using PHP and mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the records (model_name) from the mySQL database, however there are a lot models that have the same exact name. How can I omit showing for example `A5` 10 times, and show it only one?

```
$query="SELECT id,model_name FROM cars WHERE model_make_id='$country'";
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select rows with a *unique* `model_name`, then you should use the `DISTINCT` mysql keyword. That way it won't return multiple rows with that same field value.

`$query="SELECT DISTINCT model_name FROM cars WHERE model_make_id='$country'";`

Comment: Please explain the answer, else you risk downvotes from people like me, who despite code only answers.

Comment: Thank you for this, I left only the model_name because having also the id doesn't give me the expected result. How can I get the id by the way? Should I make a new query ?

Comment: Yep, sorry, if you want id's as well, I think you'd want to use `GROUP BY`. Not quite sure which you're wanting though.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/144ec/1**  Notice that the value of `5` is in there 3 times but this results in only one row for it, not 3.  Is this what you are wanting?  If you want the text with the ID then this is it.  Otherwise, please describe your end goal.

```
CREATE TABLE CARS 
(
    id int, 
    model_name varchar(20), 
);

INSERT INTO CARS (MODEL_NAME, ID) VALUES
('Email_Car', '1'),
('Twitter_Car', '1'),
('Twitter_Car', '2'),
('Twitter_Car', '3'),
('Twitter_Car', '4'),
('Twitter_Car', '5'),
('Twitter_Car', '5'),
('Twitter_Car', '5');

select model_name, id from cars
group by model_name, id
```

Comment: You might want to post that code here. Link goes dead and this answer is suddenly wrong.

Comment: What does grouping by both type and details do?

Comment: Did you post this to the correct question?  `type`, `details`, `supportContacts`?

Comment: @ginovva320 `GROUP BY` is handy for using aggregate functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html.  Example, change the select in my answer to: `select model_name, id, count(*) from cars group by model_name, id` and you will see that there is 1 of each model/id combination except for number 5, there it shows 3.

Comment: I understand `GROUP BY` somewhat. I guess I was wondering what the difference would be of `GROUP BY model_name` and `GROUP BY model_name, id`.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the LIMIT clause on your MySQL.

```
$query="SELECT id,model_name FROM cars WHERE model_make_id='$country' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: OP is asking how to make something not show several times and have several results, not how to limit the query to one row only

Comment: Thanks, at least for explaining why you downvoted it.  You're the first person to do so for me.